# Como posso indicar a directoria onde os meus assemblies devem ser encontrados?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

A minha empresa tem uma instalação que atinge a casa dos gigabytes.
A gente tem um conjunto de aplicações na nossa instalação que partilham as mesmas bibliotecas.

Por omissão, quando o .NET executa uma aplicação ele procura os *assemblies* na mesma directoria onde se encontra o executável. Além disto ele também tem em consideração os *assemblies* encontrados na GAC `%windir%\assembly` ou `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`.

Para reduzir o tamanho da minha instalação eu tinha pensado em colocar os *assemblies* comuns numa directoria partilhada. Há forma de fazer isso?

Exemplo (estrutura duma intalação convencional):

```
Aplicacao1
   Assembly1
   Assembly2
Aplicacao2
   Assembly1
   Assembly3
```

Exemplo (estrutura duma instalação com *assemblies* numa directoria partilhada, era esta que eu queria usar):

```
Aplicacao1
  Assembly2
Applicacao2
  Assembly3
lib
  Assembly1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode configurar o [`probing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Se isto não for suficiente para você precisa carregar manualmente.

Answer (score 6):

Como @Maniero mencionou, utilize a chave `probing` no seu *web.config* ou *app.config* se seu valor for estático.

Caso ele mude programaticamente, você pode utilizar [`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx) para carregar um assembly diretamente no domínio atual.